# Unable to convert Nginx access logs in Json Format

Tags: json, nginx, logging, logstash, access-log

This is my nginx log format:

```
$my_ip - - [12/Dec/2017:12:00:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 64972 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7"
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu).

I have added this in my nginx configuration:

```
log_format le_json '{"time": "$time_iso8601", '
         '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
         '"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
         '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
         '"request_time": "$request_time", '
         '"status": "$status", '
         '"request": "$request", '
         '"request_method": "$request_method", '
         '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
         '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent"}';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log le_json;
```

Reference link: https://blog.rapid7.com/2014/08/12/json-logging-in-apache-and-nginx-with-logentries/

I need to parse these logs to logstash in json format.

After adding restarted nginx but nothing changed. Same log format, can someone help?

Comment: Where do you use the tagged loggly service in your question? It seems unrelated here.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it like this? Just grok the logs in logstash and you will get them in json format or whatever output format you want.

Comment: if you put them in json format already, perhaps you can send straigth to loggly and skip logstash which is a resource hog.